# Shopware 6 Plugin JavaScript for Version 6.4 and 6.5

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have developed a shopware plugin for version 6.4 and 6.5. If I now want to use the compiled version of Shopware 6.5 in Shopware 6.4 it does not work because the JavaScript code is not executed. I need to run bin/build-storefront.sh first. It also does not work the other way around. So from Shopware 6.4 to Shopware 6.5.  My guess is that it could possibly be due to the different node versions. Shopware 6.4 requires version 12-16 and Shopware 6.5 version 18.

What would I have to do for the plugins to work directly in both versions?

Answer (score 4):

The step from `6.4` to `6.5` is a major update. This means previously deprecated code has been permanently removed, dependencies may have been removed/updated, breaking changes were introduced and backwards compatibility is explicitly not guaranteed. This includes all the tooling, e.g. the scripts for compiling assets. You'll simply have to maintain two versions until you're ready to drop support for the previous major release. Best you could do is try to keep all your uncompiled assets compatible with both major releases and have an automated workflow, e.g. a pipeline, that automatically builds releases for both versions from the same sources.

Comment: So that means publishing a plugin version 1.x for Shopware 6.4 in the store and another version series 2.x for Shopware 6.5 - right?

Comment: Right. Two version cycles with different requirements.