# How can we support both Shopware versions 6.5 and 6.4 with our plugins/apps?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

There were some breaking changes introduced in Shopware 6.5. Because of this we need to update our plugins/apps. However in some instances if we update them to work with version 6.5 they will not work with the older 6.4 version as there are some incompatible changes. For example twig template files that were renamed or twig blocks got renamed or deleted.

What would be the right approach to support both versions with our plugins/apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a new major version of your plugin and support Shopware 6.5 while still providing bugfix releases for Shopware 6.4 under the old major version.

For example if you are currently on 1.2.0 you would publish 2.0.0 for Shopware 6.5 and the next bugfix for both, 1.2.1 and 2.0.1.
It would make sense to have a dev-1.x and dev-2.x or similar branching mode in your git repository.

Also see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75868279/shopware-6-plugin-javascript-for-version-6-4-and-6-5?rq=2#comment133940628_75869056).