# Shopware 6 App storefront custom JavaScript only runs with 6.5.x not 6.4.20.x

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I have trouble with my app development. As mentioned in the title my custom JavaScript code only runs with shops with version 6.5.x but with 6.4.20.x shops you have to recompile the storefront before the code is executed. The code is bundled with the zip file inside the dist/storefront/js folder.
What can be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75869056/5419601. You can't use the same Javascript for 6.4 and 6.5 because of the major changes between these versions.